# Why is my SQL Server Query return empty record when targeting specific WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, where-clause

I was using some simple left join query like this

```
SELECT 
           A.ACCTNO
          ,[ID_Name]
          ,[ID1]
          ,[ID2]
          ,[ID3]
          ,[ID4]
          , A.Value as Value1
          , B.Value AS Value2 FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ID_Name = B.ID_Name
AND A.[ID1] = B.[ID1]
AND A.[ID2] = B.[ID2]
AND A.[ID3] = B.[ID3]
AND A.[ID4] = B.[ID4]
```

and to my surprise, some of the Value2 returns NULL value. Which should be impossible, because `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` supposed to have same exact ID, and the only different thing is the Value.

And after I did some sampling, I found out when I run this query

```
select * from TABLE_B
where ID_Name = 13
AND ID1 = 2
AND ID2 = 3
AND ID3 = 3
AND ID4 = NULL
```

It returns empty record, but when I omitted `ID4`, it return one record, and it's the record I expected :

| ID_Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 2 | NULL | 100 |

So my question is, what's triggering this. Why if I include `ID4`, it return empty record and if I left it, it return my desired output, and how can I avoid it?

**Notes :**

- Only `ID_Name` 13 that has `ID4` NULL, others `ID_Name`, has value on `ID4`, so it's not possible to exclude `ID4` on the WHERE clause
- Not sure if related, but I make datatype for `ID4` varchar(255), in case it detect `NULL` as text, because I'm using 'import' to fill the table, not using query
- `ID4` on the source flat file is leave as `BLANK`, not `NULL`

Table structure :

TABLE_A

| ID_Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 2 | NULL | 50 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 |

TABLE_B

| ID_Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 2 | NULL | 100 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 150 |

Desired Output :

| ID_Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 2 | NULL | 50 | 100 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 150 |

Current Output :

| ID_Name | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 2 | NULL | 50 | NULL |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 150 |

Comment: You used `LEFT JOIN ... ON A.ID_Name = B.ID_Name ...` which means you *expect* missing values. Why are you surprised when some values are actually missing?

Comment: Your using LEFT JOIN, change to INNER JOIN and it will force records to be in all the tables.

Comment: `ID4 = NULL` is incorrect in the where clause, you're looking for `ID4 IS NULL`

Comment: Besides, the condition you used matches if *all* the conditions are true. If there's any mismatch, you get NULLs. If either column is NULL, there's a mismatch. In SQL, the language, NULL means the value is unknown. If you compare two unknown values the result is itself unknown, so `NULL == NULL` is never true

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ,Thank you for the explanation about NULLs, is there anyway I can reference it so that I get my desired output? since I can't very well exclude ID4 just because one ID_Name doesn't use it. I cannot use Inner Join because that means it will omitted every ID_Name = 13.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, okay, then how can I reference NULL value on join clause? I can't very well use ID4 IS NULL on Join clause where in fact only ID_Name = 13 is the only ID4 that is NULL